# Why there are more than 2 solutions for $x^{14} = 1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{113}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

How to show that the equation $x^{14}=1$ has more than 2 solutions in the field $\mathbb{Z}_{113}$?

---

This is the same as solving $x^{14} \equiv 1 \pmod {113}$. I know that $x^{112} \equiv 1 \pmod {113}$ as long as $113$ does not divide $x$. But I am not sure what else can I do.

Comment: This is the same as solving x^14 = 1(mod 113). I know that x^112 = 1(mod 113) as long as 113 does not divide x. But i am not sure what else can i do.

Answer (score 5):

Hint:

$113$ is prime, so $\phi(113)=112$, which is a multiple of $14$. Remember that groups $\Bbb Z_p^\times$ are cyclic when $p$ is prime.

Comment: I see I see. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Lemma $1$: $n$'th degree polynomial has at most $n$ roots mod $p$.

Proof: Use induction. $1$'st degree polynomial $ax+b$ with $a\not\equiv 0\pmod{p}$ has at most one root mod $p$ (in fact, exactly one root mod $p$).

If every $k$'th degree polynomial has at most $k$ roots mod $p$, then prove that an arbitrary polynomial $P(x)=a_{k+1}x^{k+1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0$ with $a_{k+1}\not\equiv 0\pmod{p}$ has at most $k+1$ roots mod $p$. If $P(x)$ has no roots mod $p$, then we're done. Otherwise let $a$ be a root of $P(x)$ mod $p$. Then

$$P(x)\equiv P(x)-P(a)\equiv a_{k+1}\left(x^{k+1}-a^{k+1}\right)+\cdots+a_1\left(x-a\right)\pmod p$$

Now use the factorization $x^{k+1}-a^{k+1}=(x-a)\left(x^{k}+x^{k-1}a+\cdots+a^{k}\right)$:

$$\equiv (x-a)\left(a_n\left(x^{k}+x^{k-1}a+\cdots+a^{k}\right)+\cdots+a_1\right)\pmod p$$

The other polynomial has $k$'th degree, so by the inductive hypothesis and Euclid's Lemma the arbitrary polynomial $P(x)$ has at most $k+1$ roots mod $p$. Q.E.D.

---

Lemma $2$: If $d\mid p-1$, then $x^d\equiv 1\pmod{p}$ has exactly $d$ solutions.

Proof: $x^{p-1}-1=\left(x^d-1\right)\left(x^{(p-1)-d}+x^{(p-1)-d-1}+\cdots+1\right)$ by Fermat's Little theorem has exactly $p-1$ roots mod $p$ and by the above lemma and Euclid's Lemma the polynomials on the RHS have $d$ and $p-1-d$ roots respectively.

---

In your case, since $14\mid 113-1$, the congruence $x^{14}\equiv 1\pmod{113}$ has exactly $14$ solutions.

---

Edit: Another solution: Let $g$ be a primitive root mod $113$ (which exists because $113$ is prime). Then let $x\equiv g^k\pmod{113}$, so you're solving $g^{14k}\equiv 1\pmod{113}$, i.e. $14k\equiv 0\pmod{112}$, i.e. $k\equiv 0\pmod{8}$, so all the solutions of $x^{14}\equiv 1\pmod{113}$ are $g^0, g^{8},\ldots,g^{104}\pmod{113}$, which is $14$ solutions.

Comment: I can also convert x^14 = 1 (mod 113) to 14x = 0 (mod 112) right?

Comment: @mmarky Let $g$ be a primitive root mod $113$ (which exists because $113$ is prime). Then let $x\equiv g^k\pmod{113}$, so you're solving $g^{14k}\equiv 1\pmod{113}$, i.e. $14k\equiv 0\pmod{112}$, i.e. $k\equiv 0\pmod{8}$, so all the solutions of $x^{14}\equiv 1\pmod{113}$ are $g^0, g^{8},\ldots,g^{104}\pmod{113}$, which is $14$ solutions. Yes, you can solve it that way as well.